# How can I pass a two-dimensional array to a function in C?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int arasrc(double a[][], int r, int c, double s);

int main()
{
    double ara[3][3];
    int r, c;
    // 'ara' input
    for(r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        for(c = 0; c < 3; c++)
        {
            printf("\n\tEnter value for array (%d, %d): ", r + 1, c + 1);
            scanf("%lf", &ara[r][c]);
        }
    }
    // Printing the 'ara'
    printf("\n\tArray = ");
    for(r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        for(c = 0; c < 3; c++)
        {
            printf("[ %6.2lf ]", ara[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n\t\t");
    }
    // Searching in 'ara'
    double s;
    int found;

    printf("\n\tEnter a value to search: ");
    scanf("%lf", &s);
    found = arasrc(ara, 3, 3, s);
    if(found)
    {
        printf("\n\tFound at position (%d, %d).", (r + 1), (c + 1));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\tNot found!");
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}

// Searching in 'ara'
int arasrc(double a[][], int r, int c, double s)
{
    for(r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        for(c = 0; c < 3; c++)
        {
            if(s == a[r][c])
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have to do the coding where it asks the user to give input in a 2D array. then it prints the array and asks the user to search for a value in the array.
The main goal is to create another function for the "searching" part.

But I can't pass the array to the function. What is the problem? How can I fix the issue.

Comment: The two declarations of `arasrc` that you have doesn't match. They must match. And, the "second dimension" must be the same in both declarations, and have an actual value.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok, but not solved yet.

Comment: First of all, don't "fix" the code in your question. If you do then it's no longer a [mre] and your question becomes worthless. This site isn't here to help only you right now, it's for future visitors with the same or a similar problem as well.

Comment: Secondly, your fix was the opposite of what I suggested. You must specify the second dimension in both the prototype and definition declarations. So `double a[][]` is wrong, it needs to be `double a[][3]` at both places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it doesn't make any sense to pass r and c as parameters and then reuse them as local loop iterators. They are supposed to correspond to the sizes of the passed array or they shouldn't have been declared as parameters but local variables.

Also note that the `else { return 0; }` doesn't make sense or the program will leave the function at first iteration of the loops.

In modern C, it is recommended to pass a two-dimensional array to a function like this:

```
int arasrc (int r, int c, double a[r][c], double s)
{
    for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            if(s == a[i][j])
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Usage: `arasrc(3, 3, ara, s);`

Answer (score 2):

Include the array size. Use the following code.

```
int arasrc(double a[][3], int r, int c, double s)
{
    for(r = 0; r < 3; r ++)
    {
        for(c = 0; c < 3; c ++)
        {
            if(s == a[r][c])
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int arasrc(int a[3][3], int s)
{
    for(int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
        {
            if(s == a[r][c])
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int ara[3][3];
    int r, c;
    // 'ara' input
    for(r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        for(c = 0; c < 3; c++)
        {
            printf("\n\tEnter value for array (%d, %d): ", r + 1, c + 1);
            scanf("%d", &ara[r][c]);
        }
    }

    // Printing the 'ara'
    printf("\n\tArray = ");

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", ara[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n\t\t");
    }

    // Searching in ara
    int s;
    int found = 0;
    printf("\n\tEnter a value to search: ");
    scanf("%d", &s);
    found = arasrc(ara, s);
    if(found = 1)
    {
        printf("\n\tFound ");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\tNot found!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the solution to your question. You need to learn the syntax. Only your logic is correct.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74070203/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than a month ago"*